# Passing an argument to npm run script

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am creating a script in npm package.json.

The script will run yeoman to scaffold my template and then I want to run a gulp task to do some more stuff to a specific file (inject using [gulp-inject](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject#introduction))

The npm task looks like this:

`"scaffolt": "scaffolt -g scaffolt/generators template && gulp inject"`

Now, i need to be able to call the command from the command line giving a name to my template.

The command I need to run is the following:

`npm run scaffolt {templateName}`

but if I do this, then I try to run a gulp task called the same as the typed {templateName}.

A quick example: If I run `npm run scaffolt myTemplate` then the second part of this will try to run a task called gulp myTemplate, failing.

Is there any way to pass the {myTemplate} name as an argument to the second part of the script so that it can be used in the gulptask?

The gulp task currently only `console.log` the `process.argv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments to the npm run-script. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script#description).

Make gulp tasks for these operations.

```
//gulpfile.js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

gulp.task('inject', ['scaffolt'], () => {
  console.log('scaffolt complete!');
});
gulp.task('scaffolt', (cb) => {
  const options = commandLineArgs([{ name: 'templateName' }]);

 //use scaffolt.cmd on Windows!
 spawn('scaffolt', ['-g', 'scaffolt/generators', options.templateName])
    .on('close', cb);
});
```

And in your package

```
//package.json
"scripts": {
    "scaffolt": "gulp inject "
}
```

And to run it `npm run scaffolt -- --templateName=something`

**Tip:** npm run-script appends `node_modules/.bin` directory in the PATH so we can spawn executables just like they are on the same folder!

Comment: you don't need to change the command it should work now, if not please comment the actual command the npm runs

Comment: this is what it runs: scaffolt -g scaffolt/generators template && gulp inject "--templateName=aw
esome but it doesn't work as scaffolt syntax is scaffolt -g scaffolt/generators template {templateName} which is not comingh through

Comment: Sorry I thought you need to pass the parameter in the gulp task! Check the answer now.

Comment: I need use the postscaffolt, scaffolt works properly (with th right template name) but then gulp doesn't have it as an arg (it stops at "inject" in the array of args)

Comment: So you need this parameter in both scaffold command and gulp task. I am afraid you need a gulp task to handle this. The npm arguments will not be passed to any pre/post scripts. If you need me to explain more tell me.

Comment: I'll explain what i'm trying to do: scaffolt will generate a template with the name i provide. Then (as a sort of callback) i use the same name and i want to inject it inside a js file (which will be done using gulp-inject). 
If you can explain me how you'd do this it would be nice, thanks :)

Comment: Ok check it now!

Comment: I cannot test it. I am having issues with spawn

Answer (score 0):

You can use magical `$npm_config_<exampleVarName>` in script definition and then pass the value of it either from env variable named match `exampleVarName` or pass it in command line you add  `--exampleVarName=ValueHere`

in your case

```json
//package.json
"scripts": {
    "scaffolt": "scaffolt -g scaffolt/generators $npm_config_templateName && gulp inject"
}
```

then run it as

`npm run scaffolt --templateName=whatever`